How to add letter to equation label
I want to have a letter with my equation number, like is done in the picture I have attached.


I have done something similar in lists with
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\subscript{S}{{\arabic*}})]

I was also wondering how I could add such a label at the start of a paragraph and not just for labelling an equation.

Would the letter (say, "E") be the same for all equations in the document, or might it change at various points? If so, what determines which letter is supposed to be in use? Please advise.

I want to be able to choose it manually, as I did in the list example with \begin{enumerate}[label=(\subscript{S}{{\arabic*}})].

Your query appears to want to do three [3!] different things -- to label displayed equations, to label enumerated items, and (most recently) to label the start of a paragraph. Which one is a priority for you? Incidentally, how or where is \subscript defined?

The first part of my question is my priority, I realise now that what I want to do is not even label an equation. As the picture I gave as an example is just a line of text, with a label at the start.

I understand if this is not clear, I have set my question out in the best way. I will rewrite it and post a new question tomorrow (if it has not been answered by then).
